# Real version of Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral

Tags: integration, lie-groups, lie-algebras, random-matrices

I'm interested in an integral of the form
$$
\int_{O(d)} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}(CUAU^T)\right)dU
$$
where the integration is with respect to the Haar measure on the orthogonal group, i.e., uniform measure on *real* $UU^T=U^TU=I$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix, and let's say for simplicity $C$ is symmetric (and hence might as well be diagonal too, WLOG).

Following a [suggestion from a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/876776/134328) about this, I found [this note on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06418v1.pdf) which derives an approximation, assuming the the parameters are rational.

Do you know of any other references for this? I get that there are no nice closed form solutions unlike the unitary case, but something exact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the $O(n)$ case does not give a determinantal form. However the fact that the Lie algebra of $O(n)$ is the set of $n×n$ anti-symmetric matrices gives similar integral formulas for anti-symmetric matrices. See (1.3) and (1.4) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10691).