# Higher order partial derivatives of a product of reciprocals of cumulative sums

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-fractions

This question is related [to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691775/another-multi-dimensional-integral-with-applications-in-random-matrix-theory/4692423#4692423) where we asked for evaluating a certain multi-dimensional integral. It turns out that that integral, from the question above, can be reduced to an action of a multivariate differential operator on a certain multivariate function. Now that very action can be further simplified by an appropriate change of variables  which then leads to a quantity that we will be evaluating below. After this motivation let me formulate my question.

Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer and let $\vec{a}:= \left( a_i \right)_{i=1}^n  \in {\mathbb N}_+^n$ and let $(y_i)_{i=1}^n$ by some symbolic parameters. Define $\vec{x}:= ( x_i)_{i=1}^n$ where  $x_i := y_1+\cdots+y_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$. We define an action of a multivariate differential operator on a product of reciprocals of the quantities $x_{\cdot}$. We have:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak A}^{(\vec{a})}(\vec{x}) &:=& \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left( \sum\limits_{j=i}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right)^{a_i} \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \\
&=& \frac{\partial^{a_1}}{\partial y_1^{a_1}} \cdot 
\frac{\partial^{a_2}}{\partial y_2^{a_2}} \cdot 
\cdots 
\frac{\partial^{a_n}}{\partial y_n^{a_n}} \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(y_1+\cdots+ y_i)} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, by using iterated partial fraction decomposition  in the variables $y_i$ starting from $i=n$ all the way down to $i=1$ we have obtained the following functional form of the quantity in $(1)$. We have:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left.{\mathfrak A}^{(\vec{a})}(\vec{x}) = \right. \\
&& \left.
%
{\mathfrak T}^{(0)}(\vec{a}) + \right. \\
%
%
&& \left. 
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-2} {\mathfrak T}^{(1)}_i(\vec{y}) +
\right. \\
&& \left.
\underbrace{\cdots}_{\mbox{additional $(2^{n-1}-2-2(n-1))$ terms}} +
\right. \\
&& \left. 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} {\mathfrak T}^{(n-3)}_i(\vec{y}) +
\right. \\
&&\left.
{\mathfrak T}^{(n-2)}(\vec{a})
\right. \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak T}^{(0)}(\vec{a}) &:=& 
 \left.
%
a_n! \cdot \sum\limits_{
\begin{array}{lll} 
\left( l_j  \right. &=& 0, \cdots, (\sum\limits_{\eta=j}^n a_\eta ) - (\sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^n l_\eta ) \left. \right)_{j=2}^n
\end{array}} 
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}
{(\sum\limits_{\eta=1}^n y_\eta)^{1+ \sum\limits_{\eta=1}^n a_\eta - \sum\limits_{\eta=2}^n l_\eta}}
\cdot 
\prod\limits_{\xi=2}^n \frac{(1+ \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^n (a_\eta-l_\eta))^{(a_{\xi-1})}}{( \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^n y_\eta )^{1+l_\xi}} + \right.\\
%
{\mathfrak T}^{(1)}_i(\vec{a}) &:=& (-1)^{n-2} a_{n-i-1}!
%
\sum\limits_{
\begin{array}{lll} 
\left( l_j  \right. &=& 0, \cdots, (\sum\limits_{\eta=j}^n a_\eta ) - (\sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^n l_\eta ) \left. \right)_{j=n-i+1}^n \\
\left( l_j  \right. &=& 0, \cdots, (\sum\limits_{\eta=j}^{n-i-1} a_\eta ) - (\sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^{n-i-1} l_\eta ) \left. \right)_{j=2}^{n-i-1}
\end{array}
} 
\frac{1}{(\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^{n-i-1}y_\xi)^{1+(\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^{n-i-1} a_\xi) - (\sum\limits_{\xi=2}^{n-i-1} l_\xi) }} 
\cdot
%
\frac{1}{(\sum\limits_{\xi=n-i}^{n}y_\xi)^{1+(\sum\limits_{\xi=n-i}^{n} a_\xi) - (\sum\limits_{\xi=n-i+1}^{n} l_\xi) }} \cdot
\prod\limits_{\xi=2}^{n-i-1}
\frac{(1+ \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{n-i-1} (a_\eta-l_\eta))^{(a_{\xi-1})}}{(\sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{n-i-1} y_\eta)^{1+l_\xi}}
\cdot
\prod\limits_{\xi=n-i+1}^{n}
\frac{(1+ \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{n} (a_\eta-l_\eta))^{(a_{\xi-1})}}{(\sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{n} y_\eta)^{1+l_\xi}}
+
%
\\
%
&\vdots& \\
{\mathfrak T}^{(n-3)}_i(\vec{a}) &:=&  
\prod\limits_{\begin{array}{c} \xi=1 \\ \xi \neq (i,i+1) 
\end{array}}^n
\frac{a_\xi!}{y_{\xi}^{1+a_\xi}} \cdot 
\left(
\sum\limits_{l_{i+1}=0}^{a_{i+1}}
\frac{-(1+a_{i+1}-l_{i+1})^{(a_i)}}{(y_i+y_{i+1})^{1+a_i+a_{i+1}-l_{i+1}}} \cdot
\frac{a_{i+1}!}{y_{i+1}^{1+l_{i+1}}}
\right)
\\
%
{\mathfrak T}^{(n-2)}(\vec{a}) &:=& \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^n \frac{a_\xi!}{y_\xi^{1+a_\xi}}
\end{eqnarray}

Now the Mathematica code snippet below verifies the formula $(2)$ for $n=1,\cdots,5$. We have:

```
[![(*Our objective is to compute the following expression \partial^a\[1\] \
\partial^a\[2\] .... \partial^a\[n\] \
Product\[1/Sum\[y\[xi\],{xi,1,i}\],{i,1,n}\]. We will be using iterated \
partial fraction decomposition for this purpose.*)
uPch\[a_, n_\] := Pochhammer\[a, n\];
NN = 8; Clear\[a\]; Clear\[y\];
(*i\[Equal\]NN,NN-1,NN-2,NN-3,NN-4*)
Do\[a\[xi\] = RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\], {xi, 1, NN}\];
res = Table\[(-1)^Sum\[a\[xi\], {xi, NN - i, NN}\] D\[1/
     Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN}\], 
     Evaluate\[
      Sequence @@ Table\[{y\[xi\], a\[xi\]}, {xi, NN - i, NN}\]\]\], {i, 0, 
    4}\];
(*i=NN*)
res1 = 1/Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN - 1}\] a\[NN\]!/
   Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, NN}\]^(a\[NN\] + 1);
(*i=NN-1*)

res2 = Sum\[
    uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], 
      a\[NN - 1\]\]/(y\[NN - 1\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 2}\] + y\[NN\])^(
     a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0,
      a\[NN\]}\] + 
   uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\]/(y\[NN - 1\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 2}\])^(
    1 + a\[NN - 1\]) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1);
res2 *= a\[NN\]!/Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN - 2}\];
(*i=NN-2*)
res3 =
  Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
        a\[NN - 2\]\]/(y\[NN - 2\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 3}\] + 
         y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - 
        l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[(uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, 
       a\[NN - 2\]\])/(y\[NN - 2\] + Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, NN - 3}\])^(
     1 + a\[NN - 2\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
     a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0,
      a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[(uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
        a\[NN - 2\]\])/(y\[NN - 2\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 3}\] + 
        y\[NN - 1\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) + (
    uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\])/(y\[NN - 2\] + 
      Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, NN - 3}\])^(
    1 + a\[NN - 2\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1);

res3 *= a\[NN\]!/Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN - 3}\];
(*i=NN-3*)
res4 =
  (*One Triple sum (0,1,2)*)
  Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
        uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\] - 
           l\[NN - 2\], 
          a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\] + 
           y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
         a\[NN - 3\] + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - 
          l\[NN - 1\] - 
          l\[NN - 2\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
         l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
         a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\] - 
          l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   (*Three Double sums: (0,1),(0,2),(1,2)*)
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[
        1, a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\])^(
       1 + a\[NN - 3\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - 
        l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + 1 - l\[NN - 2\], 
        a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\] + 
         y\[NN - 2\])^(
       a\[NN - 3\] + a\[NN - 2\] + 1 - l\[NN - 2\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
       l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + 
       y\[NN\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(
     l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   Sum\[uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
       a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
       uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 2\], 
         a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\] + 
          y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
        1 + a\[NN - 3\] + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\] - 
         l\[NN - 2\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
        l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
        0 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) +
   (*Three Single sums: (0),(1),(2)*)
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
      a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\])^(
     1 + a\[NN - 3\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
     a\[NN - 2\] + 1) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
     a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0,
      a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
       a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
       a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 3\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) + 
   uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
     uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] - l\[NN - 2\], 
       a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\] + 
        y\[NN - 2\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 3\] + a\[NN - 2\] - l\[NN - 2\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
      l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 0 + a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+1)/(y\[
      NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1) +
   (*One Free term*)
   (uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
      a\[NN - 3\]\])/(y\[NN - 3\] + Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\])^(
    1 + a\[NN - 3\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(1 + a\[NN - 2\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
    a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1);


res4 *= a\[NN\]!/Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN - 4}\];

(*i=NN-4*)
S5 = Sum\[y\[xi\], {xi, 1, NN - 5}\];
res5 =
  (*One Quadruple sum (0,1,2,3)*)
  Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
        uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\] - 
           l\[NN - 2\], a\[NN - 3\]\] Sum\[
          
          uPch\[1 + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] + a\[-1 + NN\] + a\[NN\] - 
             l\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-1 + NN\] - l\[NN\], 
            a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\] + 
             y\[-1 + NN\] + y\[NN\])^(-1 - a\[-4 + NN\] - a\[-3 + NN\] - 
            a\[-2 + NN\] - a\[-1 + NN\] - a\[NN\] + l\[-3 + NN\] + 
            l\[-2 + NN\] + l\[-1 + NN\] + 
            l\[NN\]) (-1)/((y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\] + y\[-1 + NN\] + 
             y\[NN\])^(1 + l\[-3 + NN\])) , {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
           a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] + a\[-1 + NN\] + a\[NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\] -
             l\[-1 + NN\] - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + 
           y\[NN\])^(l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
         a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\] - 
          l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   (*Four triple sums: (0,1,2),(0,1,3),(0,2,3),(1,2,3)*)
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
        uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\] - 
           l\[NN - 2\], a\[NN - 3\]\] uPch\[1, 
          a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(-1 - 
          a\[-4 + NN\]) (y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\] + y\[-1 + NN\] + 
           y\[NN\])^(-1 - a\[-3 + NN\] - a\[-2 + NN\] - a\[-1 + NN\] - a\[NN\] +
           l\[-2 + NN\] + l\[-1 + NN\] + 
          l\[NN\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
         l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
         a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\] - 
          l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[
        1, a\[NN - 
          3\]\] Sum\[-uPch\[1 + a\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\], 
           a\[-4 + NN\]\] y\[-3 + NN\]^(-1 - 
          l\[-3 + NN\]) (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\])^(-1 - 
          a\[-4 + NN\] - a\[-3 + NN\] + l\[-3 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
         a\[-3 + NN\]}\] (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - 
        l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + 1 - l\[NN - 2\], 
        a\[NN - 3\]\] (Sum\[-uPch\[
            1 + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\], 
            a\[-4 + NN\]\] (y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\])^(-1 - 
           l\[-3 + NN\]) (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\] + 
            y\[-2 + NN\])^(-1 - a\[-4 + NN\] - a\[-3 + NN\] - a\[-2 + NN\] + 
           l\[-3 + NN\] + l\[-2 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
          a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\]}\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
       l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + 
       y\[NN\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(
     l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   Sum\[uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
       a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
       uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 2\], 
         a\[NN - 3\]\] (Sum\[-uPch\[
             1 + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] + a\[-1 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\] - 
              l\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-1 + NN\], a\[-4 + NN\]\] (y\[-3 + NN\] + 
             y\[-2 + NN\] + y\[-1 + NN\])^(-1 - 
            l\[-3 + NN\]) (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\] + 
             y\[-1 + NN\])^(-1 - a\[-4 + NN\] - a\[-3 + NN\] - a\[-2 + NN\] - 
            a\[-1 + NN\] + l\[-3 + NN\] + l\[-2 + NN\] + 
            l\[-1 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
           a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] + a\[-1 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\] - 
            l\[-1 + NN\]}\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
        l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
        0 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) +
   (*Six double sums: (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)*)
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[
        1, a\[NN - 3\]\] uPch\[1, a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(-1 - 
        a\[-4 + NN\])
        y\[-3 + NN\]^(-1 - 
        a\[-3 + NN\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\] - 
        l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
       l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, 
       a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 0 - l\[NN\]}\] (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\],
      0, a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
      uPch\[a\[NN - 2\] + 1 - l\[NN - 2\], 
        a\[NN - 3\]\] (uPch\[1, a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(-1 - 
          a\[-4 + NN\]) (y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\])^(-1 - a\[-3 + NN\] - 
          a\[-2 + NN\] + l\[-2 + NN\])) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
       l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + 
       y\[NN\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(
     l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0, a\[NN\]}\] + 
   Sum\[uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
      a\[NN - 3\]\] (Sum\[-uPch\[1 + a\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\], 
          a\[-4 + NN\]\] y\[-3 + NN\]^(-1 - 
         l\[-3 + NN\]) (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\])^(-1 - a\[-4 + NN\] -
          a\[-3 + NN\] + l\[-3 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
        a\[-3 + NN\]}\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
     a\[NN - 2\] + 1) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
     a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (-1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 0,
      a\[NN\]}\] +
   
   Sum\[uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
       a\[NN - 2\]\] Sum\[
       uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 2\], 
         a\[NN - 3\]\] (uPch\[1, a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(-1 - 
           a\[-4 + NN\]) (y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\] + y\[-1 + NN\])^(-1 - 
           a\[-3 + NN\] - a\[-2 + NN\] - a\[-1 + NN\] + l\[-2 + NN\] + 
           l\[-1 + NN\])) (-1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
        l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
        0 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]}\] (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) +
   Sum\[uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], 
       a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
       a\[NN - 3\]\] (Sum\[-uPch\[1 + a\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\], 
           a\[-4 + NN\]\] y\[-3 + NN\]^(-1 - 
          l\[-3 + NN\]) (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\])^(-1 - 
          a\[-4 + NN\] - a\[-3 + NN\] + l\[-3 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
         a\[-3 + NN\]}\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\] + y\[NN - 1\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\]) (-1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) +
   Sum\[(Sum\[(-uPch\[
            1 + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\], 
            a\[-4 + NN\]\])/(S5 + y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\])^(
         1 + a\[-4 + NN\] + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\] - 
          l\[-2 + NN\])
          uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] - l\[NN - 2\], 
          a\[NN - 3\]\]/(y\[-3 + NN\] + y\[-2 + NN\])^(
         1 + l\[-3 + NN\]), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
         a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - l\[-2 + NN\]}\]) (-a\[NN - 2\]!)/(y\[
        NN - 2\])^(l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 
      0 + a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+a\[NN - 1\]!)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/
    y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1) +
   (*Four single sums (0),(1),(2),(3)*)
   a\[NN - 4\]!/(S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(1 + a\[-4 + NN\]) a\[NN - 3\]!/
    y\[-3 + NN\]^(1 + a\[-3 + NN\]) (+a\[NN - 2\]!)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
    a\[NN - 2\] + 1)
     Sum\[(-uPch\[a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\], a\[NN - 1\]\])/(y\[NN - 1\] + y\[NN\])^(
      a\[NN - 1\] + a\[NN\] + 1 - l\[NN\]) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(l\[NN\] + 1), {l\[NN\], 
      0, a\[NN\]}\] +
   a\[NN - 4\]!/(S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(1 + a\[-4 + NN\]) a\[NN - 3\]!/
    y\[-3 + NN\]^(1 + a\[-3 + NN\])
     Sum\[(-uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 1\] - l\[NN - 1\], a\[NN - 2\]\])/(y\[NN - 2\] + 
        y\[NN - 1\])^(
      1 + a\[NN - 2\] + a\[NN - 1\] - 
       l\[NN - 1\]) (+a\[NN - 1\]!)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(
      l\[NN - 1\] + 1), {l\[NN - 1\], 0, a\[NN - 1\]}\] (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1) +
   a\[NN - 4\]!/(S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(1 + a\[-4 + NN\])
     Sum\[(-uPch\[1 + a\[NN - 2\] - l\[NN - 2\], a\[NN - 3\]\])/(y\[-3 + NN\] + 
        y\[-2 + NN\])^(
      1 + a\[-3 + NN\] + a\[-2 + NN\] - 
       l\[-2 + NN\])  (a\[NN - 2\]!)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
      l\[NN - 2\] + 1), {l\[NN - 2\], 0, 0 + a\[NN - 2\]}\] (+a\[NN - 1\]!)/(y\[
      NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1) + 
   Sum\[ (-uPch\[1 + a\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\], a\[-4 + NN\]\])/(S5 + 
        y\[-4 + NN\] + y\[-3 + NN\])^(
      1 + a\[-4 + NN\] + a\[-3 + NN\] - l\[-3 + NN\]) (+a\[NN - 3\]!)/ (
      y\[-3 + NN\]^(1 + l\[-3 + NN\])), {l\[-3 + NN\], 0, 
      a\[-3 + NN\]}\] (+a\[NN - 2\]!)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
    1 + a\[NN - 2\]) (+a\[NN - 1\]!)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/
    y\[NN\]^(a\[NN\] + 1) +
   (*One Free term*)
   uPch\[1, a\[NN - 1\]\] uPch\[1, a\[NN - 2\]\] uPch\[1, 
     a\[NN - 3\]\] (uPch\[1, a\[-4 + NN\]\] (S5 + y\[-4 + NN\])^(-1 - 
       a\[-4 + NN\]) y\[-3 + NN\]^(-1 - a\[-3 + NN\])) (+1)/(y\[NN - 2\])^(
    1 + a\[NN - 2\]) (+1)/(y\[NN - 1\])^(a\[NN - 1\] + 1) (+1)/y\[NN\]^(
    a\[NN\] + 1);


res5 *= a\[NN\]!/Product\[Sum\[y\[eta\], {eta, 1, xi}\], {xi, 1, NN - 5}\];


(res\[\[1\]\] - res1) /. y\[j_\] -> RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\]
(res\[\[2\]\] - res2) /. y\[j_\] -> RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\]
(res\[\[3\]\] - res3) /. y\[j_\] -> RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\]
(res\[\[4\]\] - res4) /. y\[j_\] -> RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\]
(res\[\[5\]\] - res5) /. y\[j_\] -> RandomInteger\[{1, 5}\]
```

[image]

---

As you can see some terms are missing in formula $(2)$. Can we find those terms in closed form?

Answer (score 0):

Let us define $\vec{i}:=(i_\xi)_{\xi=1}^d$ subject to $i_0=-1$ and $i_{d+1}=n-1$. Then define $\chi_\xi(\vec{i}) := \sum\limits_{l=0}^d  (n-i_l-1) \cdot 1_{n-i_l-1 \ge \xi \ge n-i_{l+1}+1 }  $.
Then the action of the multivariate operator on the product of reciprocals of partial sums reads as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&& \left[ \prod\limits_{j=1}^n (-1)^{a_j} \partial_{y_j}^{a_j} \right] \cdot
\prod\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(y_1+\cdots+y_i)} =\\
&& a_n! \sum\limits_{d=0}^{n-2} (-1)^{n-1-d}
\sum\limits_{0 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_d \le n-2}
\sum\limits_{
\begin{array}{lll}
\left( \right. l_j &=& 0,\cdots, a_j + \sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^n (a_\eta-l_\eta) \left. \right)_{j=n-i_1+1}^n \\
\left( \right. l_j &=& 0,\cdots, a_j + \sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^{n-i_1-1} (a_\eta-l_\eta) \left. \right)_{j=n-i_2+1}^{n-i_1-1} \\
\left( \right. l_j &=& 0,\cdots, a_j + \sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^{n-i_2-1} (a_\eta-l_\eta) \left. \right)_{j=n-i_3+1}^{n-i_2-1} \\
&\vdots& \\
\left( \right. l_j &=& 0,\cdots, a_j + \sum\limits_{\eta=j+1}^{n-i_d-1} (a_\eta-l_\eta) \left. \right)_{j=2}^{n-i_d-1}
\end{array}
} \\
&&
\prod\limits_{\begin{array}{ccc} \xi=2 \\ \xi \neq n-i_1 \\ \xi \neq n-i_2 \\ \vdots \\ \xi \neq n_{i_d} \end{array}}^n
\frac{\left( 1 +  \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{\chi_\xi(\vec{i})} (a_\eta-l_\eta)\right)^{(a_{\xi-1})}}{\left( \sum\limits_{\eta=\xi}^{\chi_\xi(\vec{i})} y_\eta \right)^{1+l_\xi}}
\cdot
\prod\limits_{l=1}^{d+1} \frac{(a_{n-1-i_l})!}{\left( \sum\limits_{\xi=n-i_l}^{n-i_{l-1}-1} y_\xi\right)^{1+a_{n-i_l} + \sum\limits_{\xi=n-i_l+1}^{n-i_{l-1}-1} (a_\xi-l_\xi)}} + \\
&&
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^n \frac{a_\xi!}{(y_\xi)^{1+a_\xi}} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Before we proceed let us make a comment.

The multivariate sum on the very right in the middle row runs over $(n-1-d)$  indices independently.Those indices are $(l_2,\cdots, l_{n-i_d-1}, l_{n-i_d+1}, \cdots, l_{n-i_1-1},l_{n-i_1+1}, \cdots, l_n )$. In other words the indices $l_{n-i_1}, l_{n-i_2}, \cdots, l_{n-i_d} $ are missing.It would be good to find a closed form expression for the total number of terms in that multivariate sum.

In order to be absolutely sure that this is all correct we present two code snippets that evaluate expression $(1)$ for $N=6,7$. Here we go:

###### $N=6$ :

```
In[1]:= NN = 6; Clear[a, y];
uPch[a_, n_] := Pochhammer[a, n];
Do[a[xi] = RandomInteger[{1, 3}], {xi, 1, NN}];
(*From the defintion using Mathematiuca's D[..,] command.*)
res = (-1)^Sum[a[xi], {xi, 1, NN}] D[1/
    Product[Sum[y[eta], {eta, 1, xi}], {xi, 1, NN}], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{y[xi], a[xi]}, {xi, 1, NN}]]];

(*From the closed form expression.*)
Clear[ii, ll, i, j, k, xi, jt];
res6 =
  (*One five-fold sum *)
  (-1)^-1 Sum[
     1/(0 + Sum[y[eta], {eta, NN - 5, NN}])^(
      1 + a[NN - 5] + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, NN - 4, NN}])
       Product[
       Pochhammer[1 + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, xi, NN}], 
        a[xi - 1]]/Sum[y[eta], {eta, xi, NN}]^(
       1 + ll[xi]), {xi, NN - 4, NN}], 
     Evaluate[
      Sequence @@ 
       Table[{ll[jt], 0, 
         a[jt] + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, jt + 1, NN}]}, {jt, NN, 
         NN - 4, -1}]]] +
   (*Binomial[5,d] multivariate sums of depth 5-d.*)
   Sum[(-1)^(-d - 1) 1/a[NN]! Sum[Sum[
       (Product[
           a[NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1]!/(If[eta == d + 1, 0, 0] + 0 + 
              Sum[y[xi], {xi, NN - ii[eta], NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1}])^(
            1 + a[NN - ii[eta]] + 
             Sum[a[xi] - ll[xi], {xi, NN - ii[eta] + 1, 
               NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1}]), {eta, 1, 
            d + 1}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, ii[d + 1] :> 5})
        (Times @@ 
          Delete[Table[
            With[{upLim = (Sum[(NN - ii[eta] - 1) If[
                    NN - ii[eta] - 1 >= xi >= NN - ii[eta + 1] + 1, 1,
                     0], {eta, 0, d}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, 
                  ii[d + 1] :> 5})}, 
             uPch[1 + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, xi, upLim}], 
               a[xi - 1]]/Sum[y[eta], {eta, xi, upLim}]^(
              1 + ll[xi])], {xi, NN, NN - 4, -1}], 
           Table[{ii[eta] + 1}, {eta, 1, d}]])
       , Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
                      
         Delete[Table[
           With[{upLim = (Sum[(NN - ii[eta] - 1) If[
                   NN - ii[eta] - 1 >= jt >= NN - ii[eta + 1] + 1, 1, 
                   0], {eta, 0, d}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, 
                 ii[d + 1] :> 5})}, {ll[jt], 0, 
             a[jt] + 
              Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, jt + 1, upLim}]}], {jt, NN, 
            NN - 4, -1}], Table[{ii[eta] + 1}, {eta, 1, d}]]
                     ]
       ], 
      Evaluate[
       Sequence @@ 
        Table[{ii[eta], If[eta == 1, 0, ii[eta - 1] + 1], 
          Min[NN - 2, 4]}, {eta, 1, d}]]], {d, 1, Min[NN - 2, 4]}] +
   (*One Free term*)
   (-1)^-6 a[NN - 5]!/(0 + y[NN - 5])^(1 + a[NN - 5])
     Product[a[xi]!/(y[xi])^(1 + a[xi]), {xi, NN - 4, NN}]/a[NN]!;

res6 *= a[NN]!;

(*Compare.*)
(res - res6) /. y[j_] -> RandomInteger[{1, 5}]

Out[8]= 0
```

###### $N=7$ :

```
NN = 7; Clear[a, y];
uPch[a_, n_] := Pochhammer[a, n];
Do[a[xi] = RandomInteger[{1, 3}], {xi, 1, NN}];
(*From the defintion using Mathematiuca's D[..,] command.*)
res = (-1)^Sum[a[xi], {xi, 1, NN}] D[1/
    Product[Sum[y[eta], {eta, 1, xi}], {xi, 1, NN}], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{y[xi], a[xi]}, {xi, 1, NN}]]];

(*From the closed form expression.*)
Clear[ii, ll, i, j, k, xi, jt];
res7 =
  (*One six-fold sum *)
  (-1)^-0 Sum[( 1/(0 + Sum[y[eta], {eta, -5 + NN, NN}] + y[-6 + NN])^(
       1 + a[-6 + NN] + 
        Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, -5 + NN, NN}])) Product[
       Pochhammer[1 + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, xi, NN}], 
        a[xi - 1]]/Sum[y[eta], {eta, xi, NN}]^(
       1 + ll[xi]), {xi, NN - 5, NN}], 
     Evaluate[
      Sequence @@ 
       Table[{ll[jt], 0, 
         a[jt] + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, jt + 1, NN}]}, {jt, NN, 
         NN - 5, -1}]]] +
   (*Binomial[6,d] multivariate sums of depth 6-d.*)
   Sum[(-1)^-d 1/a[NN]! Sum[Sum[
       (Product[
           a[NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1]!/(If[eta == d + 1, 0, 0] + 0 + 
              Sum[y[xi], {xi, NN - ii[eta], NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1}])^(
            1 + a[NN - ii[eta]] + 
             Sum[a[xi] - ll[xi], {xi, NN - ii[eta] + 1, 
               NN - ii[eta - 1] - 1}]), {eta, 1, 
            d + 1}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, ii[d + 1] :> 6})
        (Times @@ 
          Delete[Table[
            With[{upLim = (Sum[(NN - ii[eta] - 1) If[
                    NN - ii[eta] - 1 >= xi >= NN - ii[eta + 1] + 1, 1,
                     0], {eta, 0, d}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, 
                  ii[d + 1] :> 6})}, 
             uPch[1 + Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, xi, upLim}], 
               a[xi - 1]]/Sum[y[eta], {eta, xi, upLim}]^(
              1 + ll[xi])], {xi, NN, NN - 5, -1}], 
           Table[{ii[eta] + 1}, {eta, 1, d}]])
       , Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
                      
         Delete[Table[
           With[{upLim = (Sum[(NN - ii[eta] - 1) If[
                   NN - ii[eta] - 1 >= jt >= NN - ii[eta + 1] + 1, 1, 
                   0], {eta, 0, d}] /. {ii[0] :> -1, 
                 ii[d + 1] :> 6})}, {ll[jt], 0, 
             a[jt] + 
              Sum[a[eta] - ll[eta], {eta, jt + 1, upLim}]}], {jt, NN, 
            NN - 5, -1}], Table[{ii[eta] + 1}, {eta, 1, d}]]
                     ]
       ], 
      Evaluate[
       Sequence @@ 
        Table[{ii[eta], If[eta == 1, 0, ii[eta - 1] + 1], 
          Min[NN - 2, 5]}, {eta, 1, d}]]], {d, 1, Min[NN - 2, 5]}] +
   (*One free term*)
   (-1)^-6 (uPch[1, a[-6 + NN]] (0 + y[-6 + NN])^(-1 - 
       a[-6 + NN]) ) Product[a[xi]!/(y[xi])^(
      1 + a[xi]), {xi, NN - 5, NN}]/a[NN]!;

res7 *= a[NN]!;


(*Compare.*)
(res - res7) /. y[j_] -> RandomInteger[{1, 5}]

Out[16]= 0
```