# A closed form expression for spectral moments of arbitrary order in the Wishart ensemble

Tags: brownian-motion, random-matrices, moment-problem

We are interested in calculating the spectral moments of random matrices sampled from [the Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).
Let $N,T$ be positive integers with $T> N$ .
Then the quantities in question are defined as $m_p:= 1/N \cdot Tr \left[ c^p \right]$ where $p \in {\mathbb Z}$ and where $c:= 1/T \cdot {\bf X}  \cdot {\bf X}^T$ is the sample correlation matrix and ${\bf X}:= \left( X_{i,t} \right)_{i=1,t=1}^{N,T}$ is a random matrix with iid entries being sampled from a normal distribution with mean zero and variance one.

Let us define ${\mathfrak P}_{N,T} = \frac{\pi ^{\frac{N^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} (N-1) N} 2^{-\frac{N T}{2}}}{\left(\prod
   _{j=0}^{N-1} \Gamma \left(\frac{N-j}{2}\right)\right) \prod _{j=0}^{N-1} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{T-j}{2}\right)}$ and ${\mathfrak a} := (T-N-1)/2 $. Then, as it turns out,  those spectral moments adopt a following neat closed form expression:

\begin{eqnarray}
m_p = \frac{{\mathfrak P}_{N,T}}{N \cdot T^p} \cdot 2^{\binom{N+1}{2} +N {\mathfrak a} +p} \cdot 
\sum\limits_{J=1}^N
\left. \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^N ( \partial_{{\bar A}_\xi} + \cdots +  \partial_{{\bar A}_N} )^{{\mathfrak a} + \delta_{\xi,J} p} \cdot \prod\limits_{1 \le \xi < \eta \le N} ( \partial_{{\bar A}_\xi} + \cdots + \partial_{{\bar A}_{\eta-1}} ) \cdot \prod\limits_{\eta=1}^N \frac{1}{{\bar A}_\eta} \right|_{{\bar A}_\eta=\eta} \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Equation $(1)$ follows from the knowledge of the joint distribution of eigenvalues in the Wishart ensemble (see

*Harnad, John (ed.)*, [**Random matrices, random processes and integrable systems**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-9514-8), CRM Series in Mathematical Physics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-9513-1/hbk; 978-1-4419-9514-8/ebook). xviii, 524 p. (2011). [ZBL1215.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1215.15002)-Theorem 7.1.2 "Wishart Distribution" section 7.1.1  page 445).

That distribution involves and integral over the orthogonal group -- the [so called Itzykson-Zuber-Harish-Chandra integral](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/) -- which is unsolved.
However, in the case when the underlying correlation matrix in the ensemble in question is an identity matrix  the aforementioned integral reduces to a unity and a neat closed form expression is obtained, an expression which can be then interpreted as the distribution of energies in the so called Dyson Brownian motion model (see

*Dyson, F. J.*, [**A Brownian-motion model for the eigenvalues of a random matrix**](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1703862), J. Math. Phys. 3, 1191-1198 (1962). [ZBL0111.32703](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0111.32703).).

The evaluation of the spectral moments reduces then to evaluating a multi-dimensional integral over the  Weyl chamber, a task that can be then translated to evaluating an action of a multivariate differential operator on a product of reciprocals as explained [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691775/another-multi-dimensional-integral-with-applications-in-random-matrix-theory/4692423#4692423).

---

After this lengthy introduction we tried to put our hands on equation $(1)$ and see if we can evaluate it in closed form. We took $N=2$, we expanded the multivariate differential operator and carried out  its action analytically and we arrived at a following expression:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&m_p = \frac{{\mathfrak P}_{2,T}}{2 \cdot T^p} \cdot 2^{3+2 {\mathfrak a}+p} \cdot ({\mathfrak a})! ({\mathfrak a}+p)! \cdot \left[ \right. \\
&&
%
\left. 
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{{\mathfrak a}+p} \frac{(1+{\mathfrak a}+p-l)^{({\mathfrak a})}}{1^{({\mathfrak a})}}
\cdot \frac{(l+1)}{1^{l+2}} \cdot
\frac{1}{2^{2 {\mathfrak a}+p-l+1}} +
\right. \\
&&
%
\left. 
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{{\mathfrak a}} \frac{(1+{\mathfrak a}-l)^{({\mathfrak a}+p)}}{1^{({\mathfrak a}+p)}}
\cdot \frac{(l+1)}{1^{l+2}} \cdot
\frac{1}{2^{2 {\mathfrak a}+p-l+1}}
\right. \\
&&
\left. \right] \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Then we simply evaluated expression $(2)$ for $p=0,-1,-2$ and for $T=2+1-2 p- 2 \xi$ where $\xi=0,\cdots, 3$ and we discovered the following pattern:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&
m_p =
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \mbox{if $p=0$} \\
\frac{T}{T-3} & \mbox{if $p=-1$} \\
\frac{T^2 (-1+T)}{(-5+T)(-3+T)(-2+T)} & \mbox{if $p=-2$} \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right. \tag{2a}
\end{eqnarray}

The code snippet below verifies the expressions in $(2a)$. We have:

```
In[65]:= mGamma[NN_, x_] := 
  Pi^(NN (NN - 1)/4) Product[Gamma[(2 x - j)/2], {j, 0, NN - 1}];
Pfct[NN_, T_] := 
  Pi^(NN^2/2) 2^(-NN T/2)/(mGamma[NN, NN/2] mGamma[NN, T/2]);



ll1 = Table[
  With[{T = 2 + 1 - 2 p + 2 xi}, 
   With[{a = (T - 2 - 1)/2}, 
    Pfct[2, T]/(2 T^p) 2^(3 + 2 a + p) (a + p)! a! (  
      Sum[Pochhammer[1 + a + p - l, a]/Pochhammer[1, a] (l + 1) 1/
          2^(2 a + p - l + 1), {l, 0, a + p}] + 
       Sum[Pochhammer[1 + a - l, a + p]/
          Pochhammer[1, a + p] (l + 1) 1/2^(2 a + p - l + 1), {l, 0, 
         a + 0}])]], {p, 0, -2, -1}, {xi, 0, 3}]

ll2 = Table[
   Which[p == 0, 1, p == -1, 
    With[{T = 2 + 1 - 2 p + 2 xi}, T/(T - 2 - 1)], p == -2, 
    With[{T = 
       2 + 1 - 2 p + 2 xi}, ((-1 + T) T^2)/((-5 + T) (-3 + T) (-2 + 
        T))], True, NaN], {p, 0, -2, -1}, {xi, 0, 3}];
ll1 - ll2

Out[67]= {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {5/2, 7/4, 3/2, 11/8}, {147/20, 27/7, 605/216,
   507/220}}

Out[69]= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Now I have two questions.
Firstly, can we find a closed form expression for the spectral moment in $(2)$ for arbitrary values of $p = -3,-4,\cdots$ ?

Secondly, can we find similar expressions for the moments for $N > 2 $?

Answer (score 1):

The closed form expression in question reads:

\begin{eqnarray}
m_p &=& \frac{T^{-p}(-1)^p 2^{p-1}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{T}{2}\right)_{-p}} \cdot
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{-p}
\left((-1)^{l+p}+1\right) 
   \binom{-p}{l}
\frac{
   \left(\frac{T}{2}\right)_{\frac{l+p}{2}}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}
   \right)_{\frac{l+p}{2}}
   }
\end{eqnarray}

where $p \le 0$ and $p\in {\mathbb Z}$ and $T > 1+ 2 |p|$. See [my answer to this question for the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715037/a-set-of-identities-involving-the-gaussian-hypergeometric-function-and-its-gener?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
In[1615]:= (*The pth moment for NN=2*)
p = 2; NN = 2;
Table[With[{aa = (T - NN - 1)/2}, (2 aa + p)!/(2 aa + 1)! 1/2 1/
     T^p  (Hypergeometric2F1[2, -aa - p, -2 aa - p, 2] + 
      Hypergeometric2F1[2, -aa, -2 aa - p, 2] )] - 
  Which[p <= 0, 
   2^-1  T^-p /Product[T - 1 - 2 j, {j, 1, -p}] Sum[(
     Binomial[-p, l] (1 + (-1)^(l + p)  ) Pochhammer[T/2, 
       1/2 (l + p)])/ Pochhammer[3/2, 1/2 (l + p)], {l, 0, -p}], 
   p == 1, 1, p == 2, 1 + 3/T, p == 3, 1 + 14/T^2 + 9/T, p == 4, 
   1 + 94/T^3 + 79/T^2 + 18/T, p == 5, 
   1 + 824/T^4 + 810/T^3 + 255/T^2 + 30/T, p == 6, 
   1 + 8904/T^5 + 9742/T^4 + 3723/T^3 + 625/T^2 + 45/T], {p, -6, 
  6}, {T, Max[3 - 2 p, 3], 30, 2}]



Out[1616]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```